# using custom classes in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

I create a custom class which I call MyClass in a module MyModule

```
module MyModule
 class MyClass
   def initialize
     ... # Some code here
   end
 end
end
```

I save this code in a file called mymodule.rb

I place this file in the lib directory of my rails application, and add the following line to my application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

When I fire up the rails console and try to use this file. it just doesnt work.

```
m = MyModule::MyClass.new()
NameError: uninitialized constant MyModule
from (irb):1
from /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
from /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

What do I need to do in order to be able to use that class in the rails console

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the file **my_class.rb** and place it in the directory **my_module**. That should fix your problem.